# Configure Redis connection on initialize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redis

I'm using `Predictor` gem and when I attempt to start the gem shows:

```
"redis not configured! - Predictor.redis = Redis.new" (RuntimeError)
```

So, how to configure **Redis Connection** on initialize?

thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how `Redis` is initialized in general.

Firstly, a good practice would be adding this to your `config/environments/[environment_name].rb`. So you can maintain different locations for `Redis` when you change environments.

```
config.redis_host   = "localhost"
```

Then in your application's `config/initializers` path create `redis.rb` and place the code below to initialize `Redis`.

```
require 'redis'

## Added rescue condition if Redis connection is failed
begin
  $redis = Redis.new(:host => Rails.configuration.redis_host, :port => 6379) 
rescue Exception => e
  puts e
end
```

Then you'll be able to use the global variable `$redis` within your application for `Redis`-related commands.

```
$redis.hset "my_hash", item.id, business.id
```

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160310105422/http://jimneath.org/2011/03/24/using-redis-with-ruby-on-rails.html) is a helpful article with more details.

---

Now in your case as [this documentation](https://github.com/Pathgather/predictor#getting-started) suggests, here is what you should do:

In `config/initializers/predictor.rb`,

```
Predictor.redis = Redis.new(:url => ENV["PREDICTOR_REDIS"])
```

Or, to improve performance, add *hiredis* as your driver (you'll need to     install the *hiredis* gem first)

```
Predictor.redis = Redis.new(:url => ENV["PREDICTOR_REDIS"], :driver => :hiredis)
```

Then, be sure to include `include Predictor::Base` in all models you want to use it,

```
class CourseRecommender
  include Predictor::Base
  ...
end
```

[Here](https://www.omniref.com/ruby/gems/predictor/2.0.0/symbols/Predictor/redis/singleton) is the code responsible for the error you getting.